# 1枚の画像からワールド座標を取得する

Tags: c++, アルゴリズム, opencv, camera

F地点の座標(xL,yF,zo)を求めたいです．ただし，L,F,Cの座標はわかっているものとします．
何かよい導出方法ありませんか？
考えたこととして，
カメラの外部パラメータから回転並進行列を求めるP3P問題があり，求めようとしましたが，
ワールド座標と画面座標の3つの対応付けが必要で行き詰りました．
よろしくお願いします．

[image: 説明図]

Comment: もう少し大きい(解像度の高い)画像を貼り付けてもらうか、文字に起こしてもらわないと読み取りづらい部分があると思います。

Comment: zo は何のパラメータですか?